# View Binding: Is there a way to generically inflate a layout given a layout id?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewbinding

With data binding, we have a DataBindingUtil class which has an inflate method that can handle any layout id:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(inflater, layoutId, parent, false)
```

With view binding, there doesn't appear to be a ViewBindingUtil class. Inflate methods are meant to be called on concrete binding types. But what if you don't know the concrete binding type ahead of time? One solution is running a when statement on the layoutId:

```
binding = when (layoutId) {
    R.id.layout1 -> Layout1Binding.inflate(...)
    R.id.layout2 -> Layout2Binding.inflate(...)
    R.id.layout3 -> Layout3Binding.inflate(...)
    etc...
}
```

But that's a lot of code compared to the one liner of data binding. Is there a better way? I found this 3rd party lib but it looks like it uses reflection: https://github.com/matsudamper/ViewBindingUtil

Comment: did you found a solution to this?